# Finding every set of the five consective terms of an arithmetic sequence such that the four terms of them are squares

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

> **Question** : Can we find every set of the five consective terms of an arithmetic sequence such that the four terms of them are squares?

**Motivation** : It has been known that four consecutive terms in an arithmetic sequence cannot all be squares (see [here](http://mathpages.com/home/kmath044/kmath044.htm)).

This got me interested in the above question. By using computer, I got the following examples where $CD$ represents the common difference :

$$7^2,{13}^2,{17}^2,409,{23}^2\ (CD=120)$$
$${647}^2,4688329,{2993}^2,{3637}^2,{4183}^2\ (CD=8539440)$$

However, I don't have any good idea. Can anyone help?

Comment: The link you posted analyzes this problem quite well.

Comment: Oh, I have read only the top part of the link. Thank you very much. I'll study it by myself.